# Backbone View Render with Loop no data?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

I'm currently building a backbone JS page with underscore and require, everything seems to work but my HTML gets renderd the correct number of times but without the data?

**Please check image at bottom of post, it will explain it better.**

Files :

**js/route.js** (Loads home page content fine, catergorieList is what I'm trying to render on home page )

```
define([
      'jquery',
      'underscore',
      'backbone',
      'views/home/HomeView',
      'views/categories/CategoriesView',
    ], function($, _, Backbone, HomeView, CategoriesView) {
      var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
          '*actions': 'defaultAction'
        }
      });
      var initialize = function(){

        var app_router = new AppRouter;
        app_router.on('route:defaultAction', function (actions) 
        {
            var categoriesList = new CategoriesView();
            categoriesList.render();

            var homeView = new HomeView();
            homeView.render();
        });

        Backbone.history.start();
      };
      return {
        initialize: initialize
      };
});
```

**js/views/categories/CategoriesView.js**

```
define([
      'jquery',
      'underscore',
      'backbone',
      'models/CatergoriesModel',
      'collections/CategoriesCollection',
      'text!templates/categories/categoriestemplate.html'
    ], function($, _, Backbone, catModel, catCollection, catTemplate){

      var Categories = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize:function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            this.collection = new catCollection([]);
            this.collection.bind('reset', this.render)
            this.collection.fetch();
            this.render();
        },

        render: function(){
          var data = {
            categories: this.collection.models
          };
          var compiledTemplate = _.template( catTemplate, data );
          $("#categoriesList").append(compiledTemplate);
        }

      });

      return Categories;
    });
```

**js/collections/CategoriesCollection.js**

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/CatergoriesModel'
], function(_, Backbone, CatergoriesModel) {

    var CatergoriesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: CatergoriesModel,

        initialize: function() {
            this.fetch({
                success: this.fetchSuccess,
                error: this.fetchError
            });
        },

        url: function() {
            return 'api/categories.json';
        },

        fetchSuccess: function(collection, response) {
            return response._embedded.categories;
        },

        fetchError: function(collection, response) {
            throw new Error("Books fetch error");
        }

    });
    return CatergoriesCollection;
});
```

**js/models/CatergoriesModel.js**

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
], function(_, Backbone) {
    var CatergoriesModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
    return CatergoriesModel;
});
```

**templates/categories/categoriestemplate.html**

```
<% _.each(categories, function(category) { %> 
    <li data-catid="<%= category.id %>">
        <a href="#category/<%= category.id %>">
            <span class="fa fa-angle-double-right text-primary"></span><%= category.name %>
        </a>
    </li>
<% }); %>
```

[image]
    API Data

```
     "_embedded":{
          "categories":[
             {
                "id":1342,
                "name":"Engineers",

             {
                "id":1344,
                "name":"Squash Courts",

             }...
```

Comment: You don't seem to be passing any data to your template, your passing *this* which is your view, but not your actual collection data.

Comment: I tried this.collection and this.model but it was saying undefined

Comment: fetch, is asynchronous so when you call render the collection hasn't yet fetched it's results. You can call render in the success callback.

Comment: Can you post an answer, I still cant work this out sorry.

Comment: Updated to make easier to understand

Comment: OK I'll try and write up an answer with a jsbin to clarify

Comment: Something else to note, underscore.js changed the signature for the template method, the second argument when compiling is now the settings. To pass the data you can do something like `var template = _.template(template,settings)(data);`

Comment: Thank-you, I'm thankful for your time, been at this for 2 days now and I'm so close!

Comment: Can you post your categoriestemplate  template as well?

Comment: Just updated, if you need anything else please say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes that your making. First your trying to parses your json in the [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) success callback, you should instead be overriding your collections [parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) method for that.

For example :

```
  parse: function (response) {
      return response._embedded.categories;
    }
```

The second issue is one of timing, you are calling render on your collection view right after instantiating it, but at that point your fetch call might not have completed yet. Instead you can call your view's render method in the fetch callback.

For example

```
   initialize:function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            var self = this;
            this.collection = new CatergoriesCollection();
            this.collection.fetch({
              success: function () {
                 self.render();
              }
             });
     },
```

Finally you aren't creating your data object right or passing it to your template correctly.

To get the data from your models you can use the collections [toJSON](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON) method

```
  var data = {
        categories: this.collection.toJSON()
      };
```

And then pass it in to the **compiled** [template](http://underscorejs.org/#template) (as of underscore 1.7.0 you can no longer pass in the data while compiling the template).

```
$("#categoriesList").append(compiledTemplate(data));
```

And here's a link to a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qifiwuyuta/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: You absolute star, If i could give you bounty I would, thankyou for explaining the whole reasons why I went wrong.